# In node.js, why is there a util.isArray and an Array.isArray?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I just noticed the API docs for [Node.js v0.10.26](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_isarray_object) provide for `util.isArray`,

> util.isArray(object)# Returns true if the given "object" is an Array.
>
> false otherwise.

```
var util = require('util');
util.isArray([])
  // true
util.isArray(new Array)
  // true
util.isArray({})
  // false
```

But, how is that different ecmascripts normal, [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)?

```
> Array.isArray([]);
true
> Array.isArray(new Array);
true
> Array.isArray({});
false
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

To actually answer *why* `util.isArray` exists, we need a bit of a history lesson.

When it was [first added to node](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/3c7873bd/lib/sys.js#L194-198), it did a bit more than call `Array.isArray`.

```
function isArray (ar) {
  return ar instanceof Array
      || Array.isArray(ar)
      || (ar && ar !== Object.prototype && isArray(ar.__proto__));
}
```

This was a local function in utils and actually wasn't [exported](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/b8f3e18a5d3b9542e452274adb5422dfc0784e15) until v0.6.0.

In this form, `util.isArray` handled a case that `Array.isArray` doesn't:

```
> x = [1,2,3]
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
> y = Object.create(x)
[ , ,  ]
> Array.isArray(y)
false
> Array.isArray(Object.getPrototypeOf(y))
true
```

[There's some discussion here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs-dev/sIlwFm5GcM8) about this behavior of `util.isArray`, and consensus was that this behavior is actually bad because `y` is not really an `Array`.

Thus, the prototype-checking functionality was [soon removed and replaced](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/2dbb470) with a check that used both `Array.isArray` and a check of the argument's [*[[Class]]*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2).

```
function isArray(ar) {
  return Array.isArray(ar) ||
         (typeof ar === 'object' && objectToString(ar) === '[object Array]');
}
```

However, checking the *[[Class]]* is actually duplicate effort because `Array.isArray` [also checks](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.3.2) the *[[Class]]*, so it too was eventually [removed](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/5fcd6e403) – leaving only a call to `Array.isArray`.

Today, `util.isArray` is just an [alias](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/95dbb6b) of `Array.isArray`.

So in other words, the existence of `util.isArray` is mostly a legacy thing and can be safely ignored.

Comment: Where can I read about the differences in `y=Object.create(x)` and `x` as far as the user is concerned? That thread linked shows the member functions being different. Also, in the first implimentation of when `util.isArray` was added wouldn't it have failed that test because `util.isArray(y)`'s call to `Array.isArray(y)` would have failed?

Comment: `Object.create` instantiates a new object and sets its prototype to the object passed as the first argument.  It's a way to achieve classical inheritance or to instantiate an object without invoking its constructor.  More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) and [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/object.create-the-new-way-to-create-objects-in-javascript.html).

Comment: ...and no, that first implementation of `isArray` used the short-circuiting OR operator (`||`).  So if the argument was `instanceof Array`, it would return true.  If not, it would then call `Array.isArray` and return if true.  If not, *then* it would do the prototype check and return true or false.

Comment: Lol, I see my bad overlooked that too quick.

Comment: `+1` extra winnage for digging down into `Array.isArray`'s implementation. I wish SO had more of this kind of answer! (Amazing I have to work my way around a plus one. I wish SO had less of this kind of fascist bizarro content control).

Comment: If util.isArray is only there for legacy support, and Array.isArray was there first, then why do so many modules insist on using util.isArray instead of Array.isArray? Especially when they perform the same thing, and a dev can save a precious line by ommiting the `require('util')`

Answer (score 7):

While the Node.js source uses them both, `util.isArray` uses `Array.isArray` internally ([source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/8874a317484b8865c5fbad74d3af6155994df583/lib/util.js#L508))

In `util.js`:

```
function isArray(ar) {
  return Array.isArray(ar);
}
exports.isArray = isArray;
```

Answer (score 3):

[@SomeKittens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1216976/somekittens-ux2666) was right, but that's a week ago. [I patched node.js core and the docs](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/95dbb6b). Now they're both the same thing, or will be in due time.

```
> Array.isArray === util.isArray;
true
```

Answer (score 0):

It's for consistency reasons.

node.js has `util.isFunction()`, `util.isObject()`, `util.isArray()` and a number of similar functions. This way, type checks will all look similar to each other, instead of using different looking code each time.

Comment: This is speculative and incorrect.  `Array.isArray` is mostly used throughout node core, although there are a few `util.isArray` calls scattered throughout as well (so much for consistency).  `util.isArray` was [originally exported as a user convenience](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs-dev/sIlwFm5GcM8), not because it's something used in other core modules.

Comment: inside of util.js only `isArray` is used

Comment: There's only [one single call](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.26/lib/util.js#L249) to `isArray` inside of util, and it's older than any of the [developments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22848148/201952) made since util's `isArray` was introduced.  If that line of code were written today, it would just call `Array.isArray`.

Comment: util is deprecated as of now